# iPhone/Android App Deployment via NFC

Tags: android, ios, nfc

is it possible or not?

I've read about that Android is reading tags as you walk by, if you have NFC enabled and automatically

> Starts an activity based on the intent. This is described in How NFC Tags are Dispatched to Applications.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#tag-dispatch

Could it be possible to send a URL to download an application? Like you could deploy an ad-hoc iphone/ipad app.

And how would this work in an iOS environment?

just curious to know...

Comment: No iOS devices have NFC.

Comment: @danielbeard hm.. ok, that german wikipedia entry for NFC is misleading, it states that NFC is on iOS... damn

Comment: I'm not sure about 3rd party accessories, but none of the devices include NFC themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could it be possible to send a URL to download an application?

You could send a URL that *eventually* downloads an application. The user would have to be involved in the process.

> And how would this work in an iOS environment?

It wouldn't, as at the present time iOS does not support NFC.